# RecursionError: trouble

Tags: python, django, django-models

models.py

```
from django.db import models


CATEGORY_CHOICES=(
          ( "A" ," ACTION"),
          ("D"  ,"DRAMA"),
          ("C" , "COMEDY"),
          ("R" ,"ROMANTIC"),
)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description  = models.TextField( max_length =1000)
    image =models.ImageField(upload_to ='movies')
    category =models.CharField(choices= CATEGORY_CHOICES ,max_length =1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

urls.py

```
from  .  import views
from django.urls import  path


urlpatterns = [
    path('', MovieList.as_view() , name = 'move_list'),
    path('<int:pk>' MovieDetail.as_view(), name='movie_detail'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from  django.views.generic import ListView ,DetailView
from . models import Movie

# Create your views here.

class MovieList(ListView):
    models= Movie


class MovieDetail(DetailView):
    model = Movie
```

i don't know how to state problem
this is error
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.8/inspect.py", line 2479, in **init**                       self._kind = _ParameterKind(kind)                   File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.8/enum.py", line 304, in **call**                           return cls.**new**(cls, value)                    RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Comment: Please try to produce a minimal example which does not contain any non-neccessary information. Also: please put the question in front of the code: E.g. "Where does the RecursionError come from?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second path and importing view has bug.

```
    from  .view  import MovieList, MovieDetail
    from django.urls import  path
    urlpatterns = [
    path('', MovieList.as_view() , name = 'move_list'),
    path('<int:pk>/',  MovieDetail.as_view(), name='movie_detail'),
]
```